# Is there a way to turn off animations in github while viewing navigating through code?

Tags: github

Is there a way to turn off animations in github while viewing navigating through code? For example, if you click on a directory there is a javascript animation as it changes to present the list of the new directory's contents. It drives me nuts, so I'd like to be turn it off. I can't find anything in the github settings.

Answer (score 1):

When on github page, type this into your url bar:

```
javascript:(function(){jQuery.fx.off=true;})();
```

You can also create a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) to avoid pasting it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

If your browser supports extensions, it should be easy to create one that disables jQuery FX on all GitHub pages. The following worked for me when used as an "End Script" in Safari:

```
var killFX = document.createElement("script");
killFX.text = "jQuery.fx.off=true;";
document.body.appendChild(killFX);
```

**Update 10/04/13:** GitHub has added or changed the Content-Security-Policy header to disallow inline JavaScript:

```
X-WebKit-CSP : default-src *; script-src https://github.com https://a248.e.akamai.net https://jobs.github.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://secure.gaug.es https://gist.github.com; style-src https://github.com https://a248.e.akamai.net https://jobs.github.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://secure.gaug.es https://gist.github.com 'unsafe-inline'; object-src https://github.com https://a248.e.akamai.net
```

…which breaks the Safari extension:

```
Refused to execute inline script because of Content-Security-Policy.
```

Investigating.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could disable Javascript on github.com, but then the additional data is not loaded and you'll just see the folder names without the last checkin. I think this is the only way.